# Expanding multiple divs with content

Tags: html, css, expand

I currently have several divs creating an area for content. Two divs expand in the x axis to fill the page edge to edge, whilst two expand downwards until the content stops. I'm using a different background image in each div (62px x 62px) which repeats in the expanding four divs.

When I set my outer div height to 'auto' the other divs explode However, setting a value for height works fine? How do I get my content to take control of the height adjustment of my parent div, without the child divs exploding?

Thanks in advance!

[test site](http://www.solightingandsound.co.uk/mjnew)

HTML

```
<div id="video_outer">
<div id="video">
    <div id="v_top_left">
    </div>
        <div id="v_top">
        </div>
        <div id="v_top_right">
        </div>
        <div id="v_left">
        </div>
        <div id="v_right">
        </div>
        <div id="v_bottom_left">
        </div>
        <div id="v_bottom">
        </div>
        <div id="v_bottom_right">
        </div>  
   </div>
<div id="v_content">
    Content
    <br />
    More Content
</div>
```

CSS

```
#video_outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;        /* <<<<--- This needs to be auto */
    min-height: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 62px;

}

#v_content {
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
    top: -550px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 62px;
    padding-top: 62px;
    margin-right: 62px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 62px;
    background-image: url(images/content_fill_red.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#v_top_left {
    background-image: url(images/content_top_left_red.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    width: 62px;
    height: 62px;
    z-index: 10;
}

#v_top {
    background-image: url(images/content_top_red.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: -62px;
    width: auto;
    height: 62px;
    z-index: 5;
    margin-right: 62px;
}

#v_top_right {
    background-image: url(images/content_top_right_red.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    top: -124px;
    width: 62px;
    height: 62px;
    z-index: 10;
}

#v_left {
    background-image: url(images/content_left_red.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    position: relative;
    top: -124px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 62px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
}

#v_right {
    background-image: url(images/content_right_red.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    position: absolute;
    top: 62px;
    right: 0px;
    /*margin-left: auto;*/
    width: 62px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
}

#v_bottom_left {
    background-image: url(images/content_bottom_left_red.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: -124px;
    width: 62px;
    height: 62px;
    z-index: 10;
}

#v_bottom {
    background-image: url(images/content_bottom_red.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: -186px;
    width: auto;
    height: 62px;
    z-index: 5;
    margin-right: 62px;
}

#v_bottom_right {
    background-image: url(images/content_bottom_right_red.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    top: -248px;
    width: 62px;
    height: 62px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Sorry! could not understand your problem properly.

Comment: I see your problem, but I think you should check the position property first. You are trying to use `position: relative` together with `left:0px` for example. Either make the positions absolute and assign the left/top/... values, or keep them relative and fix it using floats. I think fixing this might shed light to why your divs are 'exploding'

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the `divs` the property of `display: inline-block;`